# (Discord.js) arr.indexOf is not a function, how do I fix this?

Tags: javascript, arrays, discord.js

I'm trying to write a Discord bot that contains several features. The main ones that are relevant to this question is a command that adds a number to a array, and one that removes a number from an array provided it exists. While I've already gotten a working "AddNumber" command completed, my main issue is in the "RemoveNumber" code. I'm using the `arr.indexOf` function to determine if it exists inside the array currently. However, whenever I attempt the function I get the error: `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: arr.indexOf is not a function`. While I have found several solutions online, and attempted most of them, none of them helped. How can I fix this? Alternatively, is there another way to check?

Relevant Code (More can be provided if needed!):

```js
// Main File (Where the array is made, passed to needed files using async)
const arr = [
    "1",
];
// End main file
// Command File
if(arr.indexOf(gametoend) === -1){
    message.reply('that game doesn\'t exist! Did you put in the wrong number?');
} else {
    message.channel.send('Placeholder success');
}
// End command file
```

Update: This is the full error text that pops up. For the question I changed the array name from inprogressgames to arr, but that isn't the case here, hence the different name.
[Image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FrmtF.png)

Update 2: Put the code in a pastebin, hopefully it helps. [Link](https://pastebin.com/JDXb1Kfg)

Comment: upload the declaration of the array

Comment: You provided the wrong piece of code ^^ your error says `inprogressgames.indexOf`, while you provided `arr.indexOf`. Please show the piece of code where the error happens

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237104/how-do-i-check-if-an-array-includes-a-value-in-javascript

Comment: @JannikSchmidtke That was on purpose to simplify the given code, I just forgot to edit it in that section. Fixed.

Comment: @ATP Its just a blank array usually, but for testing I added a single number. Fixed

Comment: The code you provided doesn't produce that error.

Comment: it works fine https://jsfiddle.net/ctvrs2wm/

Comment: I can provide a screenshot of the issue if you want. Note this is running locally, as a Discord bot, and not through a browser.

Comment: We don't have much to go on without the full code but the error means that at some point `arr` isn't an `array` so the method `indexOf` won't work. Find out when `arr` isn't an array and you will solve the issue.

Comment: @CarlMarkham I've used arrays in several other places during my project, all which worked perfectly fine, and they were built the same way as this one. Additionally, I can use ```arr.push``` to send a number to the array, and it works perfectly fine. Definitely an array.

Comment: I can guarantee it's not an array when you're calling `indexOf`, and from a quick test, it looks like it may be an `integer` https://jsfiddle.net/dwvh9zmg/ But without the full code, I'm just guessing.

Comment: Did a test, came back as an array. Will toss all my code in a pastebin and link it in the original question.

Comment: Updated the post @CarlMarkham

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the code in the paste bin I can see that `arr` isn't an `Array`. This is because of how you are calling the `execute` command:

```
await command.execute(message, args, client, arr)
```

The signature of the `execute` command only takes 3 arguments:

```
async execute(message, args, arr) {
```

Because of this, `arr` is actually the discord `client`. Either remove the `client` from the list of arguments you specify when calling `execute` or add it to the list of parameters that `execute` requires.

You can verify this by `console.log`ing `arr` just before you do the `indexOf`

[image]

There is another small issue I ran in to while debugging this and it's when you try to remove from the `array` later. `Array.remove` doesn't exist so I suggest using something like [Array.slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

Comment: The client argument is essential in another part of my code - how would I improve this code so I can use more than 3 arguments?

Comment: Add it to the list of arguments that the execute command takes: `async execute(message, args, client, arr) {`